# Is naming a class based on its implementation acceptable?

Tags: naming

Is naming a class according to its implementation an acceptable practice?

***e.g.*** `SortedSet` if the class is maintains a sorted list of unique items or `TreeSet` if it using a binary search tree structure instead.

Comment: If you've already written it, what's the current name you're using?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: @gnat I restructured the question so that it is more useful than just "name this for me"

Comment: related: [Semantic or structure - which should get preference for variable naming?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131362/semantic-or-structure-which-should-get-preference-for-variable-naming)

Comment: Seems to me SortedSet tells me how I can use it, not how you implemented it.  You could have implemented it as an array or a tree.  The sorting could be implemented in the storage or happen real time.  All I know is that I can access it in order and that it implements the rules of sets (hopefully)

Comment: This is not a general answer, just a comment on you example. In the case of a SortedSet, that really conveys useful information to the consumer. It is a set, thus every element can only appear once in the collection. It is sorted, thus if I iterate through the members, I should get them in sorted order. If the last part is not true for your implementation however, SortedSet is a very poor name.

Answer (score 7):

A class identifier should reflect things that outside users *of that class identifier* are likely to care about.  Because different users are likely to care about different things, it will generally not be possible to find a name with the "perfect" level of descriptiveness for all usage scenarios.

Note that there is a common pattern of `List foo<Bar> = new ArrayList<Bar>();`  Code which *creates* the list selects a kind of list to create, but code which *uses* the list doesn't need to use the identifier `ArrayList`.  It's debatable whether the word "Array" is semantically meaningful, or would have been omitted if such were possible.  Arguably a better pattern would have been `List foo<Bar> = List<Bar>.CreateNew();`, in which case most client code would never have to see the class name `ArrayList`; the collection types were implemented early on in the development of Java, however, and thus reflect a mixture of good and bad practices.

Note, by the way, that while Java will not allow an interface to be used in a `new` expression, there really wouldn't be anything wrong semantically with allowing programmers to say `new List()` when they want a new object which implements the `List` interface, they don't need the object to do anything beyond what's included in the interface, and they don't want to promise to refrain from using any particular features of the interface.  Most code which wants a new empty list shouldn't care whether it's backed by a single array, an array of arrays, a linked list of arrays, or some other structure.

Comment: ergo: `SortedSet` is acceptable because when client code iterates over the object it will iterate over a sorted sequence, whereas `SetTree` is unnecessary because it's implementation is of no consequence to the client code?

Comment: @ptwales: Correct, if clients are expected to care that the data is sorted, and would not be expected to care that a set was stored as a tree; a slight caveat, however, is that some people who see the name `SortedSet` might expect that for efficiency the set would require items to be added mostly in order.  A name like `SortedTreeSet` would say something about the expected performance characteristics, which clients might possibly care about.

Comment: "there really wouldn't be anything wrong semantically with allowing programmers to say `new List()`" what? how would this make any sense at all? `List` isn't a class, it doesn't contain any code, it doesn't DO anything. what would you expect it to return?

Comment: @kai: It would return an instance of some type which implements `List` in a fashion suitable for the constructor arguments (if any); the call would be equivalent to calling a static member of `List`.

Comment: what constructor? an interface by definition has no constructor, because it is not a class. there is nothing to implement the interface, because all you have is an interface. what you're describing sounds more like an abstract class with a private constructor and a private nested derived class that can be created via a static factory method.

Comment: In some object-oriented frameworks, constructors can be invoked like static methods that return the new object, and it's possible for interface types to define such functions.  This was true in the Common Object Model which preceded .NET, and even in .NET it's possible for an interface type to designate such a static method [a feature intended for compatibility with--but not restricted to--COM code].  Java doesn't provide such a feature, but it would not have been difficult to treat `new InterfaceType(params)` as syntactic sugar for `InterfaceType.ConstructDefaultTypeInstance(params)`.

Answer (score 4):

***Look no further than C++'s STL:***

```
std::map
```

> [**std::map**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a sorted
>   associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys.
>   Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare. Search,
>   removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Maps
>   are usually implemented as red-black trees.

```
std::unordered_map
```

> [**std::unordered map**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is an
>   associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys.
>   Search, insertion, and removal of elements have average constant-time
>   complexity.
>
> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but
>   organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
>   entirely on the hash of its key. This allows fast access to individual
>   elements, since once hash is computed, it refers to the exact bucket
>   the element is placed into.

```
std::set
```

> [**std::set**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an
>   associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of
>   type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison function Compare.
>   Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity.
>   Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees.

```
std::unordered_set
```

> [**std::unordered_set**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)
>   is an associative container that contains set of unique objects of
>   type Key. Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time
>   complexity.
>
> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but
>   organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
>   entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to
>   individual elements, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the
>   exact bucket the element is placed into.

I believe these examples reasonably reflect your case. This is just a smattering. There are a number of other examples.

However, note @Deduplicator's comment below, and my response. The STL names reflect differences in the how the classes can and should be used, not their internal implementations. I'm not sure about your example. If there is no impact on how a consumer interacts with the class, then IMO implementation details should not be reflected in its name. A class's name should reflect its intended usage by consumers.

If there is a significant different in performance, such as might be the case in your example, depending on the type and volume of data being stored, then perhaps a name reflecting that might work better. "SortedSet" and "QuickSet", for example, such as we find with [**Quicksort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) - although that is simply a generic name for a particular algorithm, not the formal name of a class.

Comment: The names actually reflect the contract, not the implementation. A small but important difference. (A good thing, as a user really only should care about the public interface)

Comment: @Deduplicator - I understand what you're saying and I agree. The naming here does reflect how a consumer would interact with the class, although it's not particularly explicit. My analogy to the example cited in the question is correct - but it doesn't exactly match the question as stated. The answer to the question exactly as stated - with respect to the internal implementation, would he "No", like you said.

Comment: @Deduplicator -see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Since other (Java) implementations of Collections describe their implementation, sometimes to great detail (e.g. [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)) I would say yes, naming after the implementation is fine, and is *expected*.

Unlike @supercat, I think this detailed naming is a good thing, as, unfortunately, at some point, *somebody* actually has to pick a specific implementation - a **HashMap** where things are super fast but unsorted, or a **TreeMap** which is slightly slower but things are sorted, or some **ConcurrentXXX** version?

It might be o.k. to follow his idea and have `List.newInstance()` or `Map.newInstance()`, but "they" would have to spec which kind of "default, best general purpose" implementation it does create.  This might cause a lot of arguments.

Often in my code I will implement a **protected** method to generate a new collection, e.g.

```
protected Map newMap() {
   return new HashMap();
}
```

and allow end users to override if they prefer something else.

Comment: IMHO, code should endeavor to specify what it needs, and leave open things it doesn't care about; good languages should facilitate that.  If a future version of a framework comes up with an improved "general-purpose" implementation of a base class or interface which has a different internal design, but will work interchangeably with the old one in any code which doesn't use Reflection or serialization, replacing the old implementation with a new implementation of the same class would break things, but having a factory method return the new type shouldn't break any properly-written clients.

Comment: Clients which rely upon the internal design of a class should make instances using the constructor of the exact class they want, but clients who aren't going to be concerned about the design internals should create instances in a way which would allow the framework to substitute a different class whose internals are different but whose external behavior remains the same.

Comment: @supercat I agree with you in theory.  In practice, I don't, which is why my classes often have a **protected** `newCollection()` method.  :-)  In Java, my defaults are **ArrayList** and **HashMap**.  But many of my coworkers preferred **LinkedList** and **LinkedHashMap** as defaults.  And when you now throw in concurrency I don't think anybody can pick a "reasonable" default implementation.

Comment: Having factory methods for such purposes is fine. My point was that most consumers of things like `ArrayList` don't really care whether or not all items are allocated in a single contiguous array, but some might; having code only use type `ArrayList` when it cares about such things would allow framework authors to do things differently (e.g. a `List` implementation could keep a queue of pending insert or delete requests, and handle read-by-index requests by adjusting the index based upon those pending requests; when enough items are added or deleted, or the cost of adjusting...

Comment: ...read-by-index requests gets too great, then apply all pending operations at once).  Many consumers of `List` would be happy with such an implementation, but a few might not.  If code could indicate "in advance" whether such new implementations would be desirable, that would be helpful.  Even with regard to things like concurrency, having a factory method which accepted a "requirements" parameter could be nicer than having a variety of collection types that would fit different needs, and would allow framework authors to develop more specific types when a need for them was demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself this question: "if I do this, does it make the program easier to understand?".

Outside of functionality, one of your main goals when writing code should be *clarity*. Code is read many, many times more than it is written so it should be as easy to understand as possible. Choose patterns that aid in readability.

Answer (score 1):

`SortedSet` seems perfectly fine to me. `TreeSet` might just be called `Set` but I don't think it's a huge deal. I actually like `TreeSet` better than `std::set` in C++. I might be an oddball since I'm so data-oriented. The idea behind `std::set` is that it shouldn't matter whether it's using a binary tree or a skip list for its implementation, provided it fulfills its algorithmic requirements. That's a wonderful idea except for the fact that the standard library aims to be as applicable as possible for the most performance-critical areas. Besides that, if you tell any computer scientists that you're using a "balanced binary tree" or "hash table", we already understand so much about the algorithmic complexity of your data structure without pages and pages of documentation. If you ask me, that's very concise documentation, not irrelevant implementation details! Why'd we spend all this time in CS if we're just going to use sets and maps and not care about the data structures behind them?

Of course you have to know your audience to figure out how technical or not you should be, but I'd say C++ is too difficult of a language to be trying to hide information about data structures from the C++ developer, and that C++ developers are often too performance-oriented to not care about things beyond algorithmic complexity in deciding what container or algorithm to use. I think to many of us it is worth noting that `std::sort` uses an introsort typically with a special case for sorting small ranges. We geek out on that stuff. Of course if there was a magical way to make `std::sort` the one sort to rule them all, then I'd prefer `std::sort`, at which point we can be like:

> Yep, I'm using `std::sort`. It is the fastest sort in the entire world
>   for all possible input cases for all possible vendor implementations
>   that will ever come to existence on this planet and using any other
>   sort, including Intel's own parallel sort, is just a masturbatory exercise in slowing down code.

But there is generally no algorithm to rule them all, no data structure to rule them all. Each one comes with its pros and cons that go way beyond algorithmic complexity. It is easier to answer questions about who the hottest woman is alive (Jessica Alba) than what algorithm or data structure is best. I would have preferred `introsort` for the name, and where's my `std::radix_sort`? I love radix sorts and I've replaced `std::sort` with naive radix sorts in applicable cases with reasonable boosts but I'd prefer to just use a standardized version that the C++ library implementers can micro-tune like crazy.

When performance is a concern, in practice, I often find those details about the underlying data representation just as important as the algorithmic details. For a blatant example, the fact that `vector` is implemented using a contiguous array is actually a detail that affects usage in many scenarios. That goes beyond performance. The fact that it uses an internal array makes a huge difference in whether its underlying contents can be passed along to C APIs which expect a pointer to an array, e.g. It's something worth noting and mentioning (which C++11 and beyond now do, but it wasn't always so). Beyond that, understanding its underlying data representation gives you a very precise idea of exactly how much a compacted vector will use which can be useful in those cases where we have to be frugal with memory use (embedded systems, e.g., if you are ballsy enough to use standard containers there). It isn't a good enough feeling for me if I'm working on a raytracer to just know basic things like that `std::vector` is a random-access sequence with amortized constant time `push_backs`. It is really worth noting that it's just an array which keeps track of capacity and size and reallocates when trying to insert to a full one (I even find the growth rate typically being 1.5 to 2x the former size to be of interest).

As a less blatant example, the idea that `deque` often uses page-sized blocks is a non-trivial detail important to people who use it, since the only reason you'd use `deque` over `vector` in cases where you didn't need constant-time `push_front` would be if those internal differences in data representations affect performance or robustness (for example, you might want to avoid `vector` in a case where you're tempted to allocate data larger than the OS might typically be able to find as a set of contiguous pages, since `deque` is only partially contiguous).

These details often *do matter* to the users of the library as evident by the number of people talking and speculating about the implementation details even when the authors tried not to mention it. In performance-critical areas, things like memory layout and memory usage can be just as important to note as algorithmic complexity in deciding whether or not to use this or that.

Now that's different from spilling implementation details which *never matter*, or doing so in a way that makes an interface harder to comprehend and use. For example, I don't care about the data structures internally used in a particle system in a game engine when all I can do is write code against it, since I have no choice but to use the game engine's particle system. So there it makes no sense to me to make clients have to know more than they need to know just to use the particle system. I would prefer to know the minimum in that case and let the game developers focus on the internal data representation since such knowledge wouldn't aid me in the slightest except maybe to pester the game developers about seeking more optimal representations, for which they'd probably ignore me anyway.

So err on the side of minimalism and not mentioning the details, but keep in mind that sometimes the details do matter to people using the library. When it comes to generalized data structures, I'm often hungry for more information about underlying data representations, memory layouts, and memory usage, not less.

Comment: That `vector` is compatible with a C array is promised by it's `data()` member, not by it's internal implementation. Specifically, it *isn't* just calling `new T[size]` when it reallocates. (more like `new std::aligned_storage<T>[capacity]`)

Comment: And if you need interopability with C arrays, you still have a choice. Both `vector` and `array` have `data()` members with the same promises

Comment: That's the case with C++11 where it has become a standard guarantee, but in the 90s it wasn't always so. It used to be the case where there was no standard guarantee that `vector` was contiguous, but often people speculated that it is a reliable enough assumption that `vector` would always be internally represented as a dynamic array under the hood to access `&vec[0]` when passing a vector's contents to a C API. Back then there was no `data` method. Main point there is that these details always mattered before they were even guaranteed and documented.

Comment: ... and if anything, the fact that `vector` now documents and guarantees this with a `data` method newly added for this specific purpose kind of supports that reasoning. The underlying data representations of these containers always mattered to people in selecting their containers of choice. They're not irrelevant implementation details. Like even if `std::set` fulfilled its algorithmic requirements, people in practice are probably just as interested in its memory usage characteristics. It would not be so desirable to use `std::set` if it required 200 bytes of memory overhead per element, e.g.

Comment: As another example, people have come up with libraries like `SmallVector` in LLVM here: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1SmallVector.html. What point is there to such a container if it doesn't have any different algorithmic complexity than `std::vector`? And that's where I think the original idea of the STL as it was called back then by Stepanov made a misstep of trying to focus only on algorithmic complexity, since there's more than complexity requirements guiding our choices in performance-critical areas.

Comment: I would suggest that it was always an *intention* that these promises were part of the *interface* of the containers, but ways of *expressing that* in the older standards weren't known at the time. The newer standards represent an improvement in our collective ability to precisely define things.

Comment: Much agreed there, but I think that's where these kinds of details often did matter. There's guarantees about algorithmic complexity but my choice of using Git over SVN isn't based on algorithmic complexity, e.g. Anyway, sorry if I'm getting a bit side-tracky but I often felt that general libraries could actually document more of their performance and data representation characteristics. That's different from an ugly interface which spills implementation details in a way that makes them clunky and awkward to use.

Comment: I might be guilty of being too obsessed with the details, but the way I think about it is that `unordered_map` is always going to be a hash table and I actually preferred it name-wise when it was called `hash_map`. That's an important kind of implicit guarantee for me unless the library implementers can implement `unordered_map` in a way that is, hands-down, always better than any hash table for all possible input cases. So I actually like the data representation reflected in the name of a container.